# Yii2. Represent an image.

Tags: yii2

I use `Yii2` and `Windows 10 OS`. My images are stored in `@root/uploads` folder.
I am able to upload them via `alias` like this: 
in `config\bootstrap.php`:

```
Yii::setAlias('@root', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));
```

in `upload method`:

```
$this->imageFile->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@root') .'/uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
```

Then I try to see an image in `view`:

```
<?php echo Html::img('../../uploads/ring.jpg',['class' => 'img-center', 'width'=>150, 'heigth'=>150, 'alt'=>'no image']) ?>
```

But it is not there... What I missed? Is there some restrictions for the folder?

Answer (score 1):

do the same  with getAlias

```
<?php echo Html::img( Yii::getAlias('@root') .'/uploads/ring.jpg',
           ['class' => 'img-center', 'width'=>150, 'heigth'=>150, 'alt'=>'no image']) ?>
```

for debugging you can try  creating a proper alias for your uploads directory

```
 Yii::setAlias('@uploads', 'your_absolute_path_uploads');

 var_dump( Url::to('@uploads') );

<?php echo Html::img( Yii::getAlias('@uploads') .'/ring.jpg',
           ['class' => 'img-center', 'width'=>150, 'heigth'=>150, 'alt'=>'no image']) ?>
```

if don't work ..be sure of your web server / apache / htaccess /  redir configuration.

try using

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

<?php echo Html::img( Url::to['../../uploads/ring.jpg'],
['class' => 'img-center', 'width'=>150, 'heigth'=>150, 'alt'=>'no image']) ?>
```

Or set a proper absolute alias. This a sample for www.oracle.com .. but you should adapt to your need

```
Yii::setAlias('@oracle', 'http://www.oracle.com');
echo Url::to('@oracle');  // get URL from alias     http://www.bsourcecode.com
```

Comment: Is it working for you?? For me no( I actually tried this already before.

Comment: you have an error .. ..? var_dump the result and show me ..please?

Comment: In console I have an error: `GET http://backend.dev:82/uploads/ring.jpg 404 (Not Found)`. `backend.dev:82` is equal to `app/backend/web`. So it somehow skips `'../../'`. But why?

Comment: Please show me also the right  path  .. so i can understand you files structure ..

Comment: I have update the answer with some suggestion  .. hope useful .

Comment: I used as before `'@root'`. `var_dump( Url::to('@root') )` gives me: `string(41) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\myapp"` ;
I use `Yii2 advanced template`. I changed slash direction in `Html::img( Yii::getAlias('@root') .'\uploads\ring.jpg'...)`. And got an error: `Not allowed to load local resource`. file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Ampps/www/myapp/uploads/ring.jpg

Comment: And you have the upload dir in :\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\myapp\uploads ?

Comment: Yes. Files stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\myapp\uploads.

Comment: I have update the answer with a suggestion based on Url::to helpers .. let me know ..

Comment: I created a folder inside `backend/web/uploads`. And image loads from it. So I think the problem is that I defined `app/backend/web` as `backend.dev` in `apache`. And `img scr` thinks that this is a `root`... So I think it is not possible to go deeper then `backend.dev`. And I need probably to set my app as a root. But then all folders in app will be accessible by end users..

Comment: What is the best way to store images on server with advanced template?? Where to put them? I do not want allow users to see all images from upload folder.

Comment: Due the limitation of your apache config .. a simple solution is in common directtory .. you can add a  subdir /uploads  .. and easilyb related to this by .. relative path ../../uploads .. hope my answer and comment are useful

Comment: It works with DocumentRoot "{$path}/www/myyiiapp" in apache. But with DocumentRoot "{$path}/www/myyiiapp/backend/web" it is not possible to rich folders which are located over backend/web... I would agree with this but how to delete backend/web or frontend/web from url...

Comment: should  ../../common/uploads

Comment: Not working... I think it is impossible if DocumentRoot in apache is depper then uploads folder.

Comment: but  accessing to  backend/web/uploads from absoluto path si possibile by any application included .. right? .. so colud be useful an  absolute url to this dir from both advanced app?

Comment: With absolute path it is of course working. But in this case all uploads of all users are accessible for everyone. I do not want this. I wanted to store uploads in `app/uploads` in order to restrict access to images for everyone but allow only for necessary user. For this I will need probably implement RBAC. But I need to learn how...

Comment: The answer a provided are right respect the question you posted .. and in SO this is the correct behavior .. if you have other question you should rate properly this answer and post  the new question in a proper  way